# Laravel Vapor - Creating user fails on public dev database with error: jumpbox required

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, serverless, laravel-vapor

The Laravel Vapor database documentation states:

> To quickly create a publicly accessible database of the smallest performance class, you may use the `--dev` flag when creating your database. These small, affordable databases are perfect for testing or staging environments

I have created a dev database with the suggested `vapor database dev-db --dev` command, and a public `db.t3.micro` has been created in AWS, but when I go to add an additional user to the database with the `vapor database:user dev-db user1` command I receive an error that a jumpbox is required:

> Whoops! There were some problems with your request.
>
> - A jumpbox is required to create database users.

The documentation about private/public databases states:

> In addition, these databases may be publicly accessible (with a long, random password automatically assigned by Vapor) or private. Private databases may not typically be accessed from the public Internet. To access them from your local machine, you will need to create a Vapor jumpbox.

Since the `--dev` database creation command creates a publicly accessible database, why is an error returned stating that a jumpbox is required?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug unless you tried to create the user before the database finished provisioning

Comment: maybe a bug; yes the DB was already done provisioning in AWS when trying to create the user